# how to get the index of a particular string in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C#, I created a string test = "test2"; and I wanted to get the index of the test2 from my asp:dropdownlist.

these are the items in my drop down list

```
                test1
                test2
                test3
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: He's using c# and windforms. I downvoted because this doesn't show any effort what so ever.

Comment: check the `Value` for the dropdownlist option, or check the `SelectedIndex` for the dropdownlistm or try to explain in better words what you mean

Comment: Yeah. This is not what SO is for. Please provide an attempt at a solution.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I would if I had 19 more rep, for the same reason

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Winforms doesn't use `asp:` tags.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense `asp:DropDownList` sounds rather like aspx and webpages, no?

Comment: @Icepickle that's what I meant sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropdownList.selectedIndex always 0 (yes, I do have !isPostBack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312735/dropdownlist-selectedindex-always-0-yes-i-do-have-ispostback)

Comment: What have you tried????????  Have you even attempted to do something???  Where's your code???  Have you Google it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are lazy or not but hey maybe this is what you looking for:

```
        string test = "test2";
        int ps = yourdrplst.Items.IndexOf(yourdrplst.Items.FindByText(test));
```

Comment: I'm 11 years old. It's hard to take it all in. Understanding this and that. Thank you. The ps has the value.

Comment: That's true. I don't know the reason why you are interested on programming but hang in there little one.

Comment: @19GreenBlankets you are way ahead of most 11 year olds. Hang in there and keep on learning. Don't let the haters distract you. Thank you Martius Umali for taking the time to answer.